# How to split a slide from a powerpoint presentation using VBA or Apple script

Tags: vba, macos, applescript, powerpoint

How to split a slide from a presentation using VBA or Apple script. previously i used a VBA code to achieve the same but in powerpoint 16.13.1 I am getting an error as "Mac PPT does not support opening file in window less mode." and it was working on previous versions of PowerPoint.

```
Sub SaveSlide(lSlideNum As Long, sFileName As String)

Dim oTempPres As Presentation
Dim x As Long

ActivePresentation.SaveCopyAs sFileName
' open the saved copy windowlessly
Set oTempPres = Presentations.Open(sFileName, , , False)

For x = 1 To lSlideNum - 1
    oTempPres.Slides(1).Delete
Next

' What was slide number lSlideNum is now slide 1
For x = oTempPres.Slides.Count To 2 Step -1
    oTempPres.Slides(x).Delete
Next

oTempPres.Save
oTempPres.Close
End Sub
```

In the above code I am getting error in this line

```
Set oTempPres = Presentations.Open(sFileName, , , False)
```

Please help me.
[image: this is the error which I am getting]

Comment: Try setting the last parameter to True. E.g. this `Set oTempPres = Presentations.Open(sFileName, , , True)`

Comment: Or just leave all parameters except sFileName blank.

Comment: @RyanWildry Yes it will work but I don't want to open it. I just want to split the original presentation to slides.

Comment: Will MacPPT let you use the `Application.Visible = False` parameter? I use this to cut down on graphical refresh costs when building complicated slides. Just make the application visible again before ending the sub.